# Link menu item to network path

Tags: routes, files

I am trying to figure out a way to allow content editors to add menu items that link to Windows shared drive, example path:

file:///w:/documents/001.pdf

Any ideas how to best do this in Drupal 7?

Comment: what do you mean by menu items?

Comment: When you go to Structure > Menu and add a link. I want to link to network file.

Comment: hook_menu could do it but it will be manually

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.drupal.org/node/361535